# How to get PORT number of IEDriverServer using selenium c# web driver

Tags: c#, selenium

how to get port number in a variable when we start webdriver
[please click here for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiqbZ.png)

Comment: Default port number is 4444. refer this link to get an idea https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started